# Large array, stack overflow, and dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I am wondering how could I create and initiate this large array without resorting to vector. Basically, I have been trying to create a large 1D array whose each element is a cell of a cubic with side L=NGRID cells. NGRID is read from a parameter file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>


#define pow3(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))
#define at(ix,iy,iz) ((ix*NGRID*NGRID) + (iy*NGRID) + (iz))

std::string output_file="halo_snapshot_z0.txt"; // name of the output file
std::ofstream myoutput;

double SBOX;    // size of the box
int NGRID;      // number of grid cells

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream input_file;
    std::ostringstream para_file;

    input_file << argv[1];
    para_file << argv[2];
    std::string input_file_string = input_file.str();
    std::string para_file_string = para_file.str();

    FILE* pfile = std::fopen(para_file_string.c_str(),"r");
    if (!pfile) {
        std::cout << "Parameter file not found!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::fscanf (pfile, "%lf", &SBOX);
    std::cout << SBOX << std::endl;
    std::fscanf (pfile, "%d", &NGRID);
    std::cout << NGRID << std::endl;
    double SGRID = SBOX/NGRID;

    // Initiate the halo density array
    int* densh;
    densh = (int*) malloc(pow3(NGRID) * sizeof(int));
    std::uninitialized_fill_n(densh, pow3(NGRID), 0);

    // Read the halo catalogue
    std::ifstream ifs(input_file_string.c_str(),std::ifstream::in); // in C++, the string variable <filename> cannot be used as a parameter, instead one must use filename.c_str()
    std::string iline;

    while(std::getline(ifs, iline)) // Read one entire line from ifs
    {
        std::istringstream iss(iline); // Access the line as a stream
        // Take in only the first six columns
        long int id;
        long int host;
        int sub_no;
        double mass;
        int part_no;
        double x; // x coordinate in kpc
        double y; // y coordinate in kpc
        double z; // z coordinate in kpc
        double vx;
        double vy;
        double vz;
        double rvir;
        double rmax;
        float dummy1;
        float dummy2;
        float dummy3;
        float dummy4;
        float dummy5;
        float dummy6;
        float dummy7;
        float dummy8;
        float dummy9;
        float dummy10;
        float dummy11;
        float dummy12;
        float dummy13;
        float dummy14;
        float dummy15;
        float dummy16;
        float dummy17;
        float dummy18;
        float dummy19;
        float dummy20;
        float dummy21;
        float dummy22;
        float dummy23;
        int   dummy24;
        float dummy25;
        float dummy26;
        float dummy27;
        float dummy28;
        float dummy29;
        float dummy30;


        iss >> id >> host >> sub_no >> mass >> part_no >> x >> y >> z >> vx >> vy >> vz >> rvir >> rmax >> dummy1 >>  dummy2 >>  dummy3 >>  dummy4 >>  dummy5 >>  dummy6 >>  dummy7 >>  dummy8 >>  dummy9 >>  dummy10 >>  dummy11 >>  dummy12 >>  dummy13 >>  dummy14 >>  dummy15 >>  dummy16 >>  dummy17 >>  dummy18 >>  dummy19 >>  dummy20 >>  dummy21 >>  dummy22 >>  dummy23 >>  dummy24 >>  dummy25 >>  dummy26 >>  dummy27 >>  dummy28 >>  dummy29 >>  dummy30 ; // read the entire line

        // Select only host halos and assign them onto the grid

        if (host==0) {
            //NGP mass assignment
            float gx = x/SGRID-1.;
            float gy = y/SGRID-1.;
            float gz = z/SGRID-1.;

            int ix = (int)(gx+0.5);
            int iy = (int)(gy+0.5);
            int iz = (int)(gz+0.5);

            densh[at(ix,iy,iz)] += 1;
        }
    }

    myoutput.open (output_file.c_str(),std::ofstream::out);
    for (int i=0;i<pow3(NGRID);++i) {
        myoutput << densh[i] << '\n';
    }
    myoutput.close();
    myoutput.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me segmentation fault when I try to work with NGRID=250.
Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** edited to include the full code, sorry if it looks messy, thanks for your time!

Comment: why don't you just new[] them?

Comment: The last three lines are equivalent to `std::vector<int> densh(pow3(NGRID));`. Why do you want the headaches of managing that memory by hand?

Comment: You are heap allocating ~60mb. Shouldn't be a problem at all. Are you 100% sure this is the line that is causing a segfault? There shouldn't be a stack-overflow. You should use new. If it can't allocate, it'll throw an exception. If you use `new (no throw)` or `malloc`, then it will return `NULL`. Check the return value of the allocation to see if it fails or not. Otherwise the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: Where do you assign value for your `NGRID`?

Comment: I was just wondering why I got this segmentation fault with this array. Like you guys said, it shouldn't a problem. I actually resorted to vector and it works. So I think these lines are the problem. Thanks for comments and inputs!

Comment: @PeteBecker Simply changing those 3 lines to the one you suggested sadly didn't work for me. I had to initiate the vector by a for loop which I don't think it's clever but it works.

Comment: @Max inside the main.

Comment: Print the value of `NGRID` or use a debugger to see what value it has right before the allocation.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: @Brandon I did it right after the first time I got the error, the value of NGRID was read in correctly.

Comment: @htzfun sure, I'm gonna edit the question.

Comment: @ Oleg Bogdanov I tried new but it also didn't work for me.

Comment: Before updating `densh[at(ix,iy,iz)] += 1;`, did you check if `at(ix,iy,iz)` is lower than `pow3(NGRID)` ? Using `int ix = (int)(gx+0.5);` to convert `float` to `int` could generate a value of `ix == NGRID`... And will occur an Access Violation Exception..

Comment: @J.Piquard Hi, thanks for noticing me about that problem. I fixed the code so that the indices from at() should stay between 0 and pow3(NGRID)-1. But the segmentation fault still persists. If I use vector then there is no problem.

Comment: @MinhN Hi, after protecting by `int i = std::min((NGRID-1),(int)(gx+0.5));`, I couldn't reproduce your problem by simulating inputs. For `NGRID = 500;`, I get a 125.000.000 lines `halo_snapshot_z0.txt` text file.

Comment: @J.Piquard Hi, you are totally right, after protecting the grid indices ix-iz by that there's no more problem. Thank you, sir!